# How to add active class on click in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read and tried many solutions already, but I'm new to React and I cannot figure out how to add class {s.highlighted} when the div is clicked. Can someone please explain that to me? Here is my code but it's not written by me. I prefer to add {s.highlighted} to "ListItem" when clicked and remove it from the element that was active previously.

It looks like previous developer started doing something but it doesn't work correctly. For now is only 'test-helpers' link always highlighted. What wrong with this code?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    link: {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: theme.palette.grey[900],
    },
    highlighted: {
      backgroundColor: lighten(green[500], 0.5),
    },
  })
)

// eslint-disable-next-line
//@ts-nocheck
export const MenuItems: React.FC = () => {
  const s = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/dashboard/proxies" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <CloudDone />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Proxies" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/dashboard/permissions" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <VerifiedUser />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Permissions" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/dashboard/test-helpers" className={classnames(s.link)}>
        <ListItem className={s.highlighted}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Help />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Test Helpers" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/dashboard/plans" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <FormatListNumbered />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Plans" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/dashboard/user-management" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Person />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="User Management" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/dashboard/activate-subscription" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <PersonAdd />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Activate Subscription" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/dashboard/user-plan-limits" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <BarChartIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="User Plan Limits" />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to clicking on the outer `div` as that is the only one included in the snippet? Where do you want the `s.highlighted` toggled?

Comment: @DrewReese I want to toggle `s.highlighted` in `<ListItem>`

Comment: Which `ListItem`? The where that classname is already used, or all of them? Please try to be more clear and concise on desired behavior. And clicking just the one `div`?

Comment: Hi here, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to toggle the classes as you are wanting, you will need to create some state for the component, add an onClick, and then the logic that toggles. Something along tthose lines. Check out this article here https://www.andreasreiterer.at/dynamically-add-classes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive solution may be something like this. Don't forget to import 'useState' hook from React. You need to keep the track of the active item in the state.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
      createStyles({
        link: {
          textDecoration: 'none',
          color: theme.palette.grey[900],
        },
        highlighted: {
          backgroundColor: lighten(green[500], 0.5),
        },
      })
    )
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    //@ts-nocheck
    export const MenuItems: React.FC = () => {
      const s = useStyles()
      const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0)

      return (
        <div>
          <Link to="/dashboard/proxies" className={s.link}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(0)} className={activeItemIndex === 0 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <CloudDone />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Proxies" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
    
          <Link to="/dashboard/permissions" className={s.link}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(1)} className={activeItemIndex === 1 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <VerifiedUser />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Permissions" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
    
          <Link to="/dashboard/test-helpers" className={classnames(s.link)}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(2)} className={activeItemIndex === 2 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Help />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Test Helpers" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
    
          <Link to="/dashboard/plans" className={s.link}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(3)} className={activeItemIndex === 3 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <FormatListNumbered />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Plans" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
    
          <Link to="/dashboard/user-management" className={s.link}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(4)} className={activeItemIndex === 4 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Person />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="User Management" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
    
          <Link to="/dashboard/activate-subscription" className={s.link}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(5)} className={activeItemIndex === 5 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <PersonAdd />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Activate Subscription" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
    
          <Link to="/dashboard/user-plan-limits" className={s.link}>
            <ListItem onClick={() => setActiveItemIndex(6)} className={activeItemIndex === 6 ? s.highlighted : null}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <BarChartIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="User Plan Limits" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: I replaced `null` with `s.link` and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `NavLink` component of `react-router-dom` instead, it accepts some props which could allow you to achieve active route behavior, like you are trying to achieve.

Then you could pass `s.highlighted` to the `activeClassName` prop and modify the css to target the first child of it which will target the `ListItem` component.

Here is your updated code:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    link: {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: theme.palette.grey[900],
    },
    highlighted: {
      '& > div': {
        backgroundColor: lighten(green[500], 0.5)
      }
    },
  })
)

// eslint-disable-next-line
//@ts-nocheck
export const MenuItems: React.FC = () => {
  const s = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/proxies" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <CloudDone />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Proxies" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/permissions" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <VerifiedUser />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Permissions" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/test-helpers" className={classnames(s.link)}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Help />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Test Helpers" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/plans" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <FormatListNumbered />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Plans" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/user-management" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Person />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="User Management" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/activate-subscription" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <PersonAdd />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Activate Subscription" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName={s.highlighted} to="/dashboard/user-plan-limits" className={s.link}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <BarChartIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="User Plan Limits" />
        </ListItem>
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  )
}
```